# how to do pagination with elasticsearch? from vs scroll API

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm using elasticsearch as DB to store a large batch of log data.
I know there are 2 ways to do pagination:

1. Use size and from API
2. Use scroll API

Now I'm using 'from' to do pagination.Get page and size parameters from front end,and at back end(Java)

```
searchSourceBuilder.size(size);
searchSourceBuilder.from(page * size);
```

However, if `page*size` > 10000, an exception thrown from ES.

Can I use scroll API to do pagination?

I know that if I use scroll API, the `searchResponse` object will return me a `_scroll_id`, which looks like a `base64` string.

How can I control page and size?

It seems `Scroll API` only support successive page number?

Comment: Hey, Can you please mention what approach you took to solve this problem. I also implement similar pagination to show <1,2,3,4,5> button so that use can jump to any specific page.

Answer (score 5):

There is nothing in Elasticsearch which allows direct jump to a specific page as the results have to be collected from different shards. So in your case [search_after](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-search-after.html) will be a better option. You can reduce the amount of data returned for the subsequent queries and then once you reach the page which is actually requested get the complete data.

**Example:** Let's say you have to jump to 99th page then you can reduce the amount of data for all 98th pages request and once you're at 99 you can get the complete data.

Comment: what do you mean reduce amount of data? is it ```size``` param

Answer (score 1):

What you said is correct!

You can't do traditional pagination by using scroll API.

I might suggest you to look the [Search After API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-search-after.html)

This might not help you to cover your requirement!

The `From / Size` default max result size is 10,000.

As it is mentioned [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-from-size.html)

> > Note that `from + size` can not be more than the `index.max_result_window` index setting which defaults to 10,000

So if you somehow increase the `index.max_result_window` setting persistent then it will increase the max number of search result! But this might not be the solution but decrease the limitation.

**Remember this above solution might hamper the performance of your ES server. [Read through all the posts here.](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/making-index-max-result-window-setting-persistent/63273)**

**My suggestion is to use Scroll API and change the pagination style**

Comment: Thanks for you help,I've learned a lot from your suggestion.I'll consider that.Like you said 'Using scroll API and change the pagination style' ,so ,I'd like to ask what is your pagination style?Now my pagination style is like five paging number,previous page,next page ,first page,last page (|< <1,2,3,4,5> >|)

Comment: The Scroll/Scan/Search API can be use to get searched the data without any limitation. But your have to call for next chunk of result data within your defined time limit. But main problem is you can not think of it to paginate.. Just have to use it like scroll. I mean no way to back/forward in any page. You can use caching in frontend for backward page data.

Comment: Sir,the thing is that only this module use ES as a DB,the others use Maria DB. Besides,all of the pages use pagination.So ,I have to make it looks like the others.I must have page number and size.Now I want to disable 'first page' and 'last page' button.The scroll API may not suit for this situation.